# How to change the font-size in JS to fit its container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am making a Simple Calculator App using vanilla `JS` and I have a `div` element to display the numbers. But when the `textContent` within it exceeds its width it starts looking ugly. I want to make the `font-size` smaller so that its always within the width.

This is how I am adding numbers to my display `div`

```
for(let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
    numbers[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        display.textContent += this.textContent;
    })
}
```

> When the `textContent` is less it looks good

[image]

> But when the `textContent` exceeds the width it looks bad

[image]

The original code here.

```js
//Selectors
let numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers")
let operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operators")

let equalto = document.querySelector(".equalto")
let clear = document.querySelector(".clear")
let backspace = document.querySelector(".backspace")
let plusMinus = document.querySelector(".plus-minus")
let dot = document.querySelector(".dot")

let display = document.querySelector(".display")
let output = document.querySelector(".output")

let equaltoPressed = false;

//Event Listeners
for(let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
 numbers[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (equaltoPressed){
   display.textContent = "";
   equaltoPressed = false;
  }
  //if condition so that if the display has "Infinity" on it, we don't append digits
  if ("0123456789.+-×÷".includes(display.textContent[display.textContent.length-1]) || display.textContent == "")
   display.textContent += this.textContent;
  evaluate();
 })
}

for(let i=0; i<operators.length; i++){
 operators[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
  equaltoPressed = false;
  if ("+-×÷".includes(display.textContent[display.textContent.length-1]))
   display.textContent = display.textContent.substring(0,display.textContent.length-1) + this.textContent;
  else
   display.textContent += this.textContent;
 })
}

equalto.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
 if (output.textContent !== ""){
  display.textContent = output.textContent;
  output.textContent = "";
  equaltoPressed = true;
 } 
});

clear.addEventListener("click", function(){
 equaltoPressed = false;
 display.textContent = "";
 output.textContent = "";
})


backspace.addEventListener("click", function(){
 equaltoPressed = false;
 display.textContent = display.textContent.substr(0,display.textContent.length-1);
 evaluate();
})


plusMinus.addEventListener("click", function(){
 equaltoPressed = false;
 let expression = display.textContent;
 let flag = true;

 for (let i=expression.length-1; i>=0; i--){
  if ("+-×÷".includes(expression[i])){
   if (expression[i] !== "-")
    expression = expression.substring(0,i+1) + "-" + expression.substring(i+1,expression.length);
   flag = false;
   break;
  }
 }

 if (flag)
  expression = "-"+expression;
 display.textContent = expression;

 evaluate();
})


dot.addEventListener("click", function(){
 if (equaltoPressed)
  display.textContent = "";
 let start = 0;
 for (let i=display.textContent.length-1; i>=0; i--){
  if("+-×÷".includes(display.textContent[i])){
   start = i+1;
   break;
  }
 }
 if (!display.textContent.substring(start,display.textContent.length).includes("."))
  display.textContent += ".";
})

//Functions
function evaluate(){
 let expression = display.textContent;

 for (let i=0; i<expression.length; i++){
  if (expression[i] === "×")
   expression = expression.substring(0,i) + "*" + expression.substring(i+1,expression.length);
  if (expression[i] === "÷")
   expression = expression.substring(0,i) + "/" + expression.substring(i+1,expression.length);
 }

 if("0123456789.".includes(expression[expression.length-1]) && eval(expression) != expression)
  output.textContent = eval(expression);
 else
  output.textContent = "";
}
```

```css
*{
 border:0;
 margin:0;

}

body{
 min-height: 100vh;
 background: black;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 color: #f8f8f8;
}

.row{
 display: flex;
}

.light-grey{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #a6a6a6;
 height: 4.2rem;
 width: 4.2rem;
 border-radius:  50%;
 margin: .4rem;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: black;
}

.dark-grey{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #333333;
 height: 4.2rem;
 width: 4.2rem;
 border-radius:  50%;
 margin: .4rem;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.yellow{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #ff9501;
 height: 4.2rem;
 width: 4.2rem;
 border-radius:  50%;
 margin: .4rem;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#zero{
 width: 9.2rem;
 border-radius:0 50px 50px 0;
 border-top-right-radius: 50px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
 border-top-left-radius: 50px;
}

.display{
 width: 19.2rem;
 height: 3rem;
 margin: 0 .4rem 2rem .4rem;
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 3rem;
}

.output{
 width: 19.2rem;
 height: 2rem;
 margin: 0 .4rem 2rem .4rem;
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 2rem;
}

i{
 font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-46r060N2LrChLLb5zowXQ72/iKKNiw/lAmygmHExk/o=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="display"></div>
<div class="output"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="light-grey clear">AC</div>
  <div class="light-grey plus-minus">+/-</div>
  <div class="light-grey operators">÷</div>
  <div class="yellow backspace"><i class="fas fa-backspace"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">7</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">8</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">9</div>
  <div class="yellow operators">×</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">4</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">5</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">6</div>
  <div class="yellow operators">-</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">1</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">2</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">3</div>
  <div class="yellow operators">+</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="dark-grey numbers" id="zero">0</div>
  <div class="dark-grey dot">.</div>
  <div class="yellow equalto">=</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of changing the font size, the better way may be changing scale of the container. When you receive maximum number of digits, just start calculating scale-ratio: `S = [digit container width] / [calculator container width]`, and then set the scale to fit it: `transform: scale([S]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, better view it on a **Full page**. Added a cover elements `.display-font` and `.display-cover` around `.display`, fixed their styles a little.

Then added a construction with `observer` on the end of your JS, which is looking for changing in `.display`, and then changes the `font-size: n%` of the `.display-cover` depends on the size of a `.display-font`. Here we need `.display-font` with a fixed value of `font-size`. Although we can't change `font-size` of `.display`, because we are observing the changes in it and `font-size` changes causes a circle error.

But everything works fine with 2 cover blocks. Look please.

**UPDATED**

Add everything above to `.output` block, missed it on the first try.

**UPDATE 2**

Added `white-space: nowrap;` to `.display-cover` and `.output-cover` to prevent jumping the text to the next line.

Add a lot of comments and explanations to the part of the code, where the changes in `.display` and `.output` are observing.

More about [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). It is not a quantum mechanics or a high level programming. Used it yesterday for the first time, to be honest.

More about [while statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while). Used it to check if the `.display` and `.output` width.

About rounding bug in your comment (when you are using a ling digits, more than 17 symbols).

1. This bug can be repeated in your original code.
2. This bug can be repeated in every online calculator i ever found. If you set 100000000000000000+68 - you will get 100000000000000060. This is some Javascript rounding feature. You can test it here https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Calculator-App-jQuery-Bootstrap/.

```js
//Selectors
let numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers")
let operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operators")

let equalto = document.querySelector(".equalto")
let clear = document.querySelector(".clear")
let backspace = document.querySelector(".backspace")
let plusMinus = document.querySelector(".plus-minus")
let dot = document.querySelector(".dot")

let display = document.querySelector(".display")
let output = document.querySelector(".output")

let equaltoPressed = false;

//Event Listeners
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  numbers[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (equaltoPressed) {
      display.textContent = "";
      equaltoPressed = false;
    }
    //if condition so that if the display has "Infinity" on it, we don't append digits
    if ("0123456789.+-×÷".includes(display.textContent[display.textContent.length - 1]) || display.textContent == "")
      display.textContent += this.textContent;
    evaluate();
  })
}

for (let i = 0; i < operators.length; i++) {
  operators[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    equaltoPressed = false;
    if ("+-×÷".includes(display.textContent[display.textContent.length - 1]))
      display.textContent = display.textContent.substring(0, display.textContent.length - 1) + this.textContent;
    else
      display.textContent += this.textContent;
  })
}

equalto.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (output.textContent !== "") {
    display.textContent = output.textContent;
    output.textContent = "";
    equaltoPressed = true;
  }
});

clear.addEventListener("click", function() {
  equaltoPressed = false;
  display.textContent = "";
  output.textContent = "";
})


backspace.addEventListener("click", function() {
  equaltoPressed = false;
  display.textContent = display.textContent.substr(0, display.textContent.length - 1);
  evaluate();
})


plusMinus.addEventListener("click", function() {
  equaltoPressed = false;
  let expression = display.textContent;
  let flag = true;

  for (let i = expression.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if ("+-×÷".includes(expression[i])) {
      if (expression[i] !== "-")
        expression = expression.substring(0, i + 1) + "-" + expression.substring(i + 1, expression.length);
      flag = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (flag)
    expression = "-" + expression;
  display.textContent = expression;

  evaluate();
})


dot.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (equaltoPressed)
    display.textContent = "";
  let start = 0;
  for (let i = display.textContent.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if ("+-×÷".includes(display.textContent[i])) {
      start = i + 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!display.textContent.substring(start, display.textContent.length).includes("."))
    display.textContent += ".";
})

//Functions
function evaluate() {
  let expression = display.textContent;

  for (let i = 0; i < expression.length; i++) {
    if (expression[i] === "×")
      expression = expression.substring(0, i) + "*" + expression.substring(i + 1, expression.length);
    if (expression[i] === "÷")
      expression = expression.substring(0, i) + "/" + expression.substring(i + 1, expression.length);
  }

  if ("0123456789.".includes(expression[expression.length - 1]) && eval(expression) != expression)
    output.textContent = eval(expression);
  else
    output.textContent = "";
}


// .display and .output font resizing changing addon
let displayCover = document.querySelector(".display-cover");
let outputCover = document.querySelector(".output-cover");
let displaySize;
let outputSize;
// This part is a config of MutationObserver, options for the observer (which mutations to observe) 
let config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
};

// Defining new class of the object MutationObserver, which provides the ability to watch for changes being made to the DOM tree. Basically - this class will be executed on every observing changes in '.display'.
let displayObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {

  displaySize = 100; // we will use it like a base 100% font-size later
  // set font size to '.display-cover'
  displayCover.style.cssText = 'font-size:' + displaySize + '%';
  
  // 'while' statement creates a loop that executes a specified statement as long as the test condition evaluates to true. The condition is evaluated before executing the statement. Each time we set font size -1 - the width of '.display' changes, and we keeping this loop until the width of '.display' will be not more then it's parent '.display-cover' 
  while(display.offsetWidth > displayCover.offsetWidth) {
    displaySize = displaySize - 1; //decrements font size by 1% each loop
    displayCover.style.cssText = 'font-size:' + displaySize + '%';
    // basically in DOM you see only result of the very last loop of this 'while' statment    
  } 
  
});

// Start observing the target node (your '.display') for configured mutations (using config)
displayObserver.observe(display, config);

//----------

// everything the same as above, but for '.output'
let outputObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  outputSize = 100; 
  outputCover.style.cssText = 'font-size:' + outputSize + '%';
  while(output.offsetWidth > outputCover.offsetWidth) {
    outputSize = outputSize - 1;
    outputCover.style.cssText = 'font-size:' + outputSize + '%';
  } 
});

// as you can see, 'config' is the same
outputObserver.observe(output, config);
```

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #f8f8f8;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.light-grey {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  height: 4.2rem;
  width: 4.2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: .4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

.dark-grey {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 4.2rem;
  width: 4.2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: .4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.yellow {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ff9501;
  height: 4.2rem;
  width: 4.2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: .4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#zero {
  width: 9.2rem;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
}
.display-font {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.display-cover {
  width: 19.2rem;
  height: 3rem;
  margin: 0 .4rem 2rem .4rem;
  text-align: right;  
  font-size: 100%;  
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.display {
  font-size: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.output-font {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.output-cover {
  width: 19.2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  margin: 0 .4rem 2rem .4rem;
  text-align: right;  
  font-size: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.output {
  font-size: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

i {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-46r060N2LrChLLb5zowXQ72/iKKNiw/lAmygmHExk/o=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="display-font">
  <div class="display-cover">
    <div class="display"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="output-font">
  <div class="output-cover">
    <div class="output"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="light-grey clear">AC</div>
  <div class="light-grey plus-minus">+/-</div>
  <div class="light-grey operators">÷</div>
  <div class="yellow backspace"><i class="fas fa-backspace"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">7</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">8</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">9</div>
  <div class="yellow operators">×</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">4</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">5</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">6</div>
  <div class="yellow operators">-</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">1</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">2</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">3</div>
  <div class="yellow operators">+</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="dark-grey numbers" id="zero">0</div>
  <div class="dark-grey dot">.</div>
  <div class="yellow equalto">=</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And there's some wierd bug now in the application, the addition doesn't yield appropriate results. See this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BPHa.jpg Why is the result one smaller than what it should be?

Comment: Added a lot of comments and details to the code and references to documentation. There is nothing hard, i used MutationObserver first time yesterday. About the bug - it was in your original calculator. And i fond it in every online Javascript calculate. This is some language features with rounding math with digits with 17 or more characters. And the last one - you changed the code on your reference.  The code by your link not more valid. Please return the original code to avoid misunderstanding of other readers of SO.

Comment: Unfortunately, not so beautiful in Firefox as in Chrome (because of FF's poorly behaviors with scrollbar styling). And try to use `min-height` instead of `height` in body, not all elements seen on small screens. But the calculation code is pretty good, your level is enough to learn about MutationObserver in a half of an hour maybe.

Comment: Just seen. What else you would like to discuss?